# How can I make list items line up on a grid when wrapping?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Say I have the following `<ul>` for use in a responsive design:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    MenuItemHeinz
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemHinrich
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemRoffen
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemStaffRoffeltack
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemHeinz
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I resize the browser window or look at the page in a phone it breaks like this:

[image]

How can I make the menu items instead line up nicely on a grid when they break, for example like this? Preferably only using css ... of course ;)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This layout is relatively simple with CSS [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nojtxryk/13/)

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Comment: Even more super answer and thanks for the edit of my post. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [css columns](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) and a media query.

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
@media(max-width: 680px) {
  ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
  li {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    MenuItemHeinz
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemHinrich
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemRoffen
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemStaffRoffeltack
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItemHeinz
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Super answer, and I already deployed it. But I was hoping to find a way to make the list still go left to right, **across the columns**, not up and down the rows.